# mongoengine inheritance django

Tags: django, inheritance, mongoengine

I've tried with this example: http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html?highlight=query%20document%20inheritance#posts
but not working for me.

I want to store data from weather api: 
        http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.8/?lat=46.079001;lon=14.51860012

so i have models.py like this

```
import mongoengine

class Weather(mongoengine.Document):
    created = mongoengine.DateTimeField
    latitude = mongoengine.DecimalField
    longitude = mongoengine.DecimalField
    model_name = mongoengine.StringField

class Precipitation(Weather):
    dateFrom = mongoengine.DateTimeField(required=True)
    dateTo = mongoengine.DateTimeField(required=True)
    precipitation = mongoengine.DecimalField
    symbol = mongoengine.IntField(min_value=1, max_value=23)

class State(Weather):
    temperature = mongoengine.DecimalField
    windDirection = mongoengine.StringField
    windAngle = mongoengine.DecimalField
```

Trying to save data for example:
    models.State.objects.create(temperature=17)

nothing is saved!

I know i'm missing arguments to constructor in fields definition but I don't really know how to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need class instances eg:

```
import mongoengine

class Weather(mongoengine.Document):
    created = mongoengine.DateTimeField()
    latitude = mongoengine.DecimalField()
    longitude = mongoengine.DecimalField()
    model_name = mongoengine.StringField()

class Precipitation(Weather):
    dateFrom = mongoengine.DateTimeField(required=True)
    dateTo = mongoengine.DateTimeField(required=True)
    precipitation = mongoengine.DecimalField
    symbol = mongoengine.IntField(min_value=1, max_value=23)

class State(Weather):
    temperature = mongoengine.DecimalField()
    windDirection = mongoengine.StringField()
    windAngle = mongoengine.DecimalField()
```

Comment: oh my god! i was watching the code for 2 dayys and couldn't get these small differnece xD